# JNDI configuration with jboss using oracle 11G

Tags: java, jboss, jndi

I am using jboss server Currently I am using JDBC connection,but I want to use
JNDI data source. As I am comletly new to it. Please tell me step by step How I can achive that. Also please tell me if I can deploy that as EAR(including xml file.)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/2.1.x/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html).

You usually set up a JNDI data source on the app server itself.  Of course you can deploy any application that uses it as an EAR.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you give me any exmple which file I need to include in my EAR.

Comment: That's what the link is for.

Comment: I read the doc , But can you please tell me where I can put ds.xml file

Comment: In the server /deploy directory, where it always goes.

Comment: I added the foolowing code as : web.xml like: <resource-ref> <description>DB Connection</description> <res-ref-name>jdbc/7KSD101</res-ref-name> <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type> <res-auth>Container</res-auth> </resource-ref> and I am getting exception like
java.lang.RuntimeException: mapped-name is required for jdbc/7KSD101 of deployment AUTO.war Please help.

Comment: Also my -ds.xml is like
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<datasources>
<local-tx-datasource>
<jndi-name>jdbc/7KSD101</jndi-name>
<connection-url> jdbc:oracle:thin:@tdas4280.test.sprint.com:1521:7KSD101</connection-url>

<driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
<user-name>feb09_dev</user-name>
<password>sprint$2008</password>

<!-- sql to call on an existing pooled connection when it is obtained from pool - the OracleValidConnectionChecker is prefered
<check-valid-connection-sql>some arbitrary sql</check-valid-connection-sql>
--></local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>